# Django custom manager to filter nearby through related model

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-managers

I have two models `Shop` and `Address`.

Shop `Model`:

```
class Shop(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    address = models.ForeignKey(
        Address,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    objects = LocationManager()
```

Address `Model`:

```
class Address(BaseModel):
    latitude = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=16,
        decimal_places=14, 
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    longitude = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=16,
        decimal_places=14, 
        blank=True,
        null=True
     )
     status = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)
```

I have created a custom Manager for Shop model

```
class LocationManager(models.Manager):
    def nearby(self, latitude, longitude, proximity):
        """
        Return all object which distance to specified coordinates
        is less than proximity given in kilometers
        """
        # Great circle distance formula
        # acos will not work in sqlite
        gcd = """
            6371 * acos(
                cos(radians(%s)) * cos(radians(latitude))
                * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(%s)) +
                sin(radians(%s)) * sin(radians(latitude))
            )
        """
        queryset =  self.get_queryset().select_related(
            'address'
        ).exclude(
            latitude=None
        )
        .exclude(
            longitude=None
        )
        .annotate(
            distance=RawSQL(
                gcd,
                (
                    latitude,
                    longitude,
                    latitude
                )
            )
        ).filter(
            distance__lt=proximity
        ).order_by('distance')

        return queryset
```

Now I want to find nearby shops using custom manager:

```
Shop.objects.nearby(13.244334,72.329832,20)
```

But i am getting this error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'latitude' into field. Choices are: address, address_id, name
```

How can I use filter my queryset by `latitude` to find nearby shop?

Answer (score 3):

Your are querying your `Shop` model, not your `Address` model.
Your `Shop` model don't have any field named `latitude`, as stated by your error.

You should use the field lookup to filter your `Shop`s by the attribute of the linked object `Address` ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api-reference))

Since your `Shop` model is linked to your `Address` model by the field `address`, to filter the `Shop` by the `Address` attributes, you can do (ie for the `latitude` field):

```
Shop.objects.filter(address__latitude=<your_lookup_here>)
```

Also, your two `exclude` methods could be rewritted like this (using the `Q` object):

```
Shop.objects.exclude(
    Q(address__latitude__isnull=True)
    | Q(address__longitude__isnull=True)
)
```

I advice you to read the documentation linked above about the queryset API.

Comment: on doing select_related() django internally does left outer join with the related table. I want to use latitude and longitude from the address table.

Comment: `select_related` add a join clause, but you still need to query the related instances attributes using the relation. I strongly advise you to read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships